# how to remove dependency error in angular + ionicframwork?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, requirejs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am try to make simple login page using require js in ionic framwork .But I am getting this error .

```
 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app.auth' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/nomod?p0=app.auth
```

could you please tell me how to remove this error .I am using ionic framwork which is combination of angular and HTML.

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/QPXDMQWDhZumeF5HGvvw?p=preview

```
define(['ionic','auth/controller/authCtrl'],function(){
    'use strict'
    angular.module("app.auth",['ionic']);
})
```

Comment: seems ng-app is missing?

Comment: I am using require js ..please check app.js

Comment: I see  angular.module("app.auth",['ionic']); but i can not find module name 'ionic' ?

Comment: @NuongNguyen how to solve the issue ..

Comment: @NuongNguyen have you used ionic with require js ?

Comment: @NuongNguyen 'ionic' it is on main.js file

Comment: Not yet, but i have used angular, require js, and some other third party, when you define angular.module("app.auth",['ionic']) make sure you have module 'inoic', if not, module app.auth will be failed , i recommend you should be read carefuly document of inoic to use it with require js and angular, maybe i will try it :D

Comment: ionic combination of angularjs all librarary check this    .                                   http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js

Comment: @NuongNguyen if you have time please look it else leave it.

Comment: Hi you can see my demo at here 
    http://plnkr.co/edit/cl7S0WF8C8fG56HUHmXF?p=preview
I hope it useful for you!